# JPQL statement returning boolean value

Tags: select, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

Is it possible to write JPQL query like following:

`select count(*) > 0 from Scenario scen where scen.name = :name`

that would return true/false boolean values depending of whether entity filling criteria exists or not?

I would like to use the query this way:

```
boolean exists = entityManager.createQuery(query,Boolean.class).setParameter("name",name).getSingleResult();
```

The query from my example just isn't syntactically correct (parse error), but is there any correct way of doing checks like that in JPQL, that would return boolean value, or is it only possible in Java code?

Comment: `SELECT NEW java.lang.Boolean(count(*) > 0)` should work. Maybe you can omit the package declaration, I have no chance to try it right now.

Comment: Strange, but I'm getting following error: `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [java.lang.Boolean] [select new java.lang.Boolean(count(*) > 0) from ...`

Comment: So try to determine what this query returns - I mean try `Object exists = entityManager.createQuery(...`, then look in the debug mode what type and value is exists Object

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with following:

```
select case when (count(scen) > 0)  then true else false end  
from Scenario scen where scen.name = :name
```

Comment: Actually this statement is valid `HQL` but not valid `JPQL`.

Comment: @Oleksandr Bondarenko, that can be, but I am unfortunately not able to recognize why exactly it is not valid JQPL, can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry, it's a valid JPQL, it was invalid in JPA 1.0.

Comment: Is it normal that this QUERY returns an `Integer` not a `Boolean`?

Comment: I've got the same issue as @JinKwon. Does anyone has a solution that would actually return a boolean with JPA?

Comment: I have it working as an @Query annotation on a Spring Data JPA repository using the exact syntax from the answer.

Comment: Confirm the usability with Spring DATA JPA and it can return boolean as it is.

Answer (score 22):

What about just:

```
select count(scen) > 0
from Scenario scen where scen.name = :name
```

Comment: Even with current Hibernate 5.2.12 this statement does not work for all Databases. It work for H2 but not for MSSQL, Instead the "case when then.." works for both (and hopefully all) Databases

Comment: i think most of projects never migrate to MSSQL from other table)

Comment: :) One of the most misunderstood, hyped “features” of Hibernate IMHO. You’ll never ever just swap your Enterprise DB without any thorough migration plan and code changes, at least not at projects of any reasonable size. If somebody really wants to switch from say Postgres to M$SQL, youl’ll have to test your codebase anyway. Fix the query and be done with it. Just don’t write complex queries from the start, just because you *might* need it sometime in the future (you never will!)

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA complained about the `>` operator until I put parentheses around the comparison: `(count(scen) > 0)`.

Comment: @JensPiegsa I think they fixed this now it works without parentheses

Comment: Hello from 2021, Idea 2021.1.1 still doesn't like expression without parentheses

Answer (score 3):

I had success with:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select if(count(name) > 0, 'true', 'false') from Scenario scene where scene.name = :name")
Boolean nameExists(@Param("name") String name);
```

NOTE: I'm using MySQL with MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, then I updated my hibernate to 4.3.11.Final and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
@Query("select count(scen) > 0 from Scenario scen where scen.name = :name")
```