# Boolean literal in CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, derby, jpql

I followed [JPQL statement returning boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051563/jpql-statement-returning-boolean-value) for checking an Entity's existance.

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN (COUNT(e) > 0L) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
FROM MyEntity AS e
WHERE ...
```

But when I tried

```java
boolean exist(...) {
    return em.createNamedQuery(<above>, Boolean.class)
        .setParameter(...)
        .getSingleResult();
}
```

complains that she can't cast an Integer into a Boolean. Is it normal?

I have to use it like this.

```java
boolean exist(..) {
    return em.createNamedQuery(<above>, Integer.class)
        .setParameter(...)
        .getSingleResult() > 0; // Shouldn't it be different from COUNT(e)?
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here comes the actual code.

```java
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Currency.NQ_EXIST_BY_HREF,
                query = "SELECT" + (" CASE WHEN (COUNT(c) > 0L)"
                                    + " THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END")
                        + " FROM Currency AS c"
                        + " WHERE c.service = :service"
                        + " AND c.href = :href")
})
@Table(name = "CURRENCY", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"SERVICE_ID", "HREF"})
})
@XmlTransient
public class Currency implements Serializable {

    public static final String NQ_EXIST_BY_HREF = "Currency.NQ_EXIST_BY_HREF";
```

Method in Test.

```java
protected static boolean NQ_EXIST_BY_HREF(
    final EntityManager manager, final String href, final Service service) {

    return manager.createNamedQuery(Currency.NQ_EXIST_BY_HREF,
                                    Boolean.class)
        .setParameter("href", href)
        .setParameter("service", service)
        .getSingleResult();
}
```

Here comes the traces.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at ....persistence.finance.CurrencyTest.NQ_EXIST_BY_HREF(CurrencyTest.java:93)
    at ....persistence.finance.CurrencyTest.newHref(CurrencyTest.java:168)
    at ....persistence.finance.CurrencyTest.testNQ_EXIST_BY_HREF(CurrencyTest.java:231)
```

I'm testing with `Derby(Memory)+EclipseLink` with following persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="localPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>...</class>
    <class>...</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:memory:corrsDB;create=true"/>
      <!--      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>-->
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="target/createDDL.jdbc"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="target/dropDDL.jdbc"/>
<!--      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>-->
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**UPDATE**

Here comes derby info.

```
databaseProductName: Apache Derby
databaseProductVersion: 10.8.1.2 - (1095077)
databaseMajorVersion: 10
databaseMinorVersion: 8
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my pom/dependencies. I'm not targeting any specific derby. I'm using the one included in JDK a.k.a. Java DB.

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <!-- this dependency must be mentioned prior to javax:javaee-api -->
      <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-testng-container</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
      <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-alpha-4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

dependency:tree

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building corrs-entities 1.0-alpha-1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ corrs-entities ---
[INFO] kr.co.ticomms.corrs:corrs-entities:jar:1.0-alpha-1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.main.extras:glassfish-embedded-all:jar:3.1.2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1:jar:1.0.0.CR3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.0.0.CR7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.0.0.CR7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.0.0.CR7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.0.0.CR7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.0.0-cr-1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api:jar:1.1.0-beta-1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.0.0.CR7:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.0.0.CR7:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-cdi:jar:1.0.0.CR7:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-ejb:jar:1.0.0.CR7:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-resource:jar:1.0.0.CR7:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext:jar:1.0.0.CR7:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.testng:arquillian-testng-container:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testng:arquillian-testng-core:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-spi:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:2.0.0-alpha-4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base:jar:2.0.0-alpha-4:test
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] \- org.testng:testng:jar:6.8:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO]    +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:test
[INFO]    +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.27:test
[INFO]    \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.6:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.442s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 15 16:28:01 KST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/221M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE**

I added explicit (latest) derby as a dependency and got no changes.

```
databaseProductName: Apache Derby
databaseProductVersion: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
databaseMajorVersion: 10
databaseMinorVersion: 9
```

**UPDATE** (WRONG)

The problem seems came from Derby. (WRONG)
See [EclipseLink JPA 2.0 case expressions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/case_expressions). (WRONG)

I changed from derby to hsqldb and it works with `Boolean.class`. (WRONG)

---

**CONCLUSION**

I was wrong. The problem is came from EclipseLink. I tested with two different provider settings.

```xml
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> <!-- doesn't work -->
```

and

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> <!-- works -->
```

Comment: You have obviously missed the `return` statement in your example. I belive that this is only misprint in question, not in your actual code. I just fixed it in your question. Approve if its so.

Comment: What version of JPA do you use?

Comment: Copy and pasted your code and it works fine, are you sure you didn't made a typo or something? I was having problems with comparing fields, maybe you're comparing Integer with Boolean on some where clause?

Comment: Odd. Please include the exception and stack. In general many databases don't have a boolean type, and use integer instead, normally 0 = false, 1 = true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that Derby does not support a boolean data-type so returns 1/0 from the query instead.
This is why is works on HSQL, as boolean are supported.

Since you have typed your named query return type, EclipseLink should be smart enough to auto-convert integer to boolean for you.  It does not seem to be doing this, so please log a bug for that.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of derby do you use ? Older versions of derby doesnt support Boolean data type. But you can use with integer values.

```
 @NamedQuery(name = Currency.NQ_EXIST_BY_HREF,
            query = "SELECT" + (" CASE WHEN (COUNT(c) > 0L)"
                                + " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
                    + " FROM Currency AS c"
                    + " WHERE c.service = :service"
                    + " AND c.href = :href")
```

Comment: I tried and got the same result. She wants `Integer.class` not `Boolean.class`.

Comment: @JinKwon jdk doesn't matter. it deals with derby.